# Proof a formula of the Fibonacci sequence with induction

Tags: proof-verification, induction, fibonacci-numbers, proof-explanation

It turns out that the Fibonacci sequence satisfies the following explicit formula: For all integers $F_{n} ≥ 0$,

$F_{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}[(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^{n+1} - (\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^{n+1}]$

Verify that the sequence defined by this formula satisfies the recurrence relation $F_{k} = F_{k-1} + F_{k-2}$ for all integers $k ≥ 2$.

Comment: Ok,so what's hard? Can't we just substitute $F_n$ directly, and use the fact that $\frac{1+\sqrt(5)}{2}$ satisfies the equation $x^2-x+1=0$?

Comment: let $(u,v)=\left(\dfrac{1\pm \sqrt 5}{2}\right)$. Show that they are the roots of $x^2=x+1$.

Comment: See https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Euler-Binet_Formula

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$F_{k} = \frac{\phi^k + \psi^k}{\sqrt{5}}$$
$$F_{k-1} + F_{k-2} = \frac{\phi^{k-1} + \psi^{k-1}}{\sqrt{5}} + \frac{\phi^{k-2} + \psi ^{k-2}}{\sqrt{5}}$$
$$= \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \left(\phi^{k-2} + \psi ^{k-2} + \phi^{k-1} + \psi^{k-1}\right)$$
From here see that
$$\phi^{k-2} + \phi^{k-1} = \phi^{k-2}(\phi + 1) = \phi^{k-2}\left(\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)$$
$$ = \phi^{k-2}\left(\frac{6+2\sqrt{5}}{4}\right) = \phi^{k-2}\left(\frac{1+2\sqrt{5}+5}{4}\right) = \phi^{k-2}\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^2 = \phi^{k-2}\phi^2 = \phi^k$$
Similarily
$$\psi^{k-2} + \psi^{k-1} = \psi^{k-2}(\psi + 1) = \psi^{k-2}\left(\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right) $$
$$ = \psi^{k-2}\left(\frac{6-2\sqrt{5}}{4}\right) = \psi^{k-2}\left(\frac{1-2\sqrt{5}+5}{4}\right) = \psi^{k-2}\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^2 = \psi^{k-2}\psi^2 = \psi^k$$
Therefore, we get that
$$F_{k-1} + F_{k-2} = \frac{\phi^k + \psi^k}{\sqrt{5}}$$